# UINavigationController's default back button is missing its arrow

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

The text is there, but the place where the arrow should be is empty. I've tried re-embedding in a new navigation controller and it doesn't fix the problem. I'm really curious where the arrow went. Even when I try to add a custom back button, the arrow is still missing. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you embedded your initial viewcontroller into a navigation controller?

Comment: yes I have....The back button text appears, but the little arrow does not. There is just a small indent where the arrow is supposed to be